# Converting C# razor function/sub to VB

Tags: c#, vb.net, razor, asp.net-mvc-5, telerik-mvc

I'm using Telerik controls in my MVC application. The demos provided are all C# and I'm struggling converion some of the helper code... in particular this:

```
.DataSource(source >=
{
    source.Read(read >=
    {
        read.Action("MyAction", "MyController");
      });
  })
```

I've tried online C# to Vb converters (even one provided by Telerik) but with no joy. Can anyone help or point me to a resource that can.

Thanks

Comment: That's not legal C#. You can't have a `.` as the initial character of a statement.

Comment: Also, should `read >= read.Action(...)` be `read => read.Action(...)`?

Comment: Are you sure `>=` is not `=>`?

Comment: That syntax looks like wrong written (@JoelCoehoorn comments) lambda expressions. Check the msdn doc https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/procedures/lambda-expressions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this:

```
read >= read.Action(...)
```

Should really be this:

```
read => read.Action(...)
```

If that's accurate, you're looking for something like this:

```
.DataSource(Function(source) source.Read(Function(read) read.Action("MyAction", "MyController")))
```

or this:

```
.DataSource(Function(source) source.Read(Sub(read) read.Action("MyAction", "MyController")))
```

Depending on whether or not `read.Action()` returns a result and what the `source.Read()` function is expecting.

You should also break that long statement up into multiple lines for readability, but I'm not in VB often enough anymore to remember exactly what the rules are for that. I'd have to let Visual Studio tell me, and you can do that for yourself much quickyer than I.

Comment: Well the >= was copied from a telerik demo page and probably explains why their converter did not work... just trying your answer.